# Cuando ejecuto mvn -version me aparece el siguiente mensaje; pregunta si tengo windows 10 porque me sale windows 8.1. Apoyo a mi consulta

Tags: maven

Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T12:29:23-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Servers\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: es_PE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Cuando descargaste maven te fijaste en la versión?